# How do I append to a data frame in a user input in loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, user-input

I am creating a sort of data entry application with r
here is the code,

```
stud_details <- function(name, parent_name, address, marks){
  repeat {
    details_frame = data.frame(name, parent_name, address, marks)
    details_frame = rbind(details_frame)
    x = readline(prompt = "Do you want to see the data frame of the details you entered (yes or no) : ")
    x = tolower(x)
    if(x == "yes")
    {
      print(details_frame)
      break
    }
  }
}

repeat{
  first_input = readline(prompt=" Do you want to enter any data (yes or no): ")
  if(first_input == "yes")
  {
    name = c((readline(prompt="Enter Name: ")))
    parent_name = c(readline(prompt="Enter Parent's Name: "))
    address = c(readline(prompt="Enter Address: "))
    marks = c(readline(prompt="Enter Marks: "))
    stud_details(name, parent_name, address, marks)
  }
  else if (first_input == "no"){
    break
  }
}
```

so this code basically asks user for student data, and then data frames it.
it does that, but the problem is that when we enter the data again, it replaces the data the was entered previously.
I tried creating a list with the 4 variables, but doesn't work ig.

i want that it should append the data.

p.s. [will make the code better once I get this :)]

Answer (score 0):

One option to make your code work would be to first create an empty dataframe for your student data. Inside your loop you could then append the data entered by the user to this dataframe. To this end I have rewritten your `student_detail` function. First, a loop is not necessary. Second, return the `details_frame`.

```
student_data <- data.frame(name = character(0), parent_name = character(0), address = character(0), marks = character(0))

stud_details <- function(name, parent_name, address, marks) {
  details_frame <- data.frame(name, parent_name, address, marks)
  x <- readline(prompt = "Do you want to see the data frame of the details you entered (yes or no) : ")
  x <- tolower(x)
  if (x == "yes") {
    print(details_frame)
  }
  return(details_frame)
}

repeat{
  first_input <- readline(prompt = " Do you want to enter any data (yes or no): ")
  if (first_input == "yes") {
    name <- c((readline(prompt = "Enter Name: ")))
    parent_name <- c(readline(prompt = "Enter Parent's Name: "))
    address <- c(readline(prompt = "Enter Address: "))
    marks <- c(readline(prompt = "Enter Marks: "))
    details_frame <- stud_details(name, parent_name, address, marks)
    student_data <- rbind.data.frame(student_data, details_frame)
  } else if (first_input == "no") {
    break
  }
}

student_data
```

Here is a small example run when running the code and adding data for two students:

[image]